# preg_match spliting one word in two, returning last character as a captured group

Tags: php, regex

This is my pattern:

```
$fullname = '/^([a-zA-Z]+)(?:[,]?[\s]?)?([a-zA-Z]+)((?:\s)([a-zA-Z]{1}))?$/i';
```

and I'm using it with `preg_match($nameReg, $value, $match)` in PHP.

I want to capture Lastname and then Firstname. Since I'll be using ajax to load results on the fly with a LIKE in my sql statement, I want to start with the lastname and not wait for the first name.

The problem is that when I only enter the lastname (first word), I get the last character of the lastname as a captured group.

```
Array
(
    [0] => SMITH
    [1] => SMIT
    [2] => H
)
```

I'd like to get

```
Array
(
    [0] => SMITH
    [1] => SMITH
)
```

but I don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: You should use the `/x` modifier to make your regex more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you require at least one letter in the second `[a-zA-Z]+`. If you make that second capturing group optional it should work:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+)(?:[,]?[\s]?)?([a-zA-Z]+)?((?:\s)([a-zA-Z]{1}))?$/i
```

However, you are using the case-insensitive flag but still provide both upper- and lower-case variants. Plus `{1}` is always redundant. Lastly, single-character character classes are unnecessary, too, and while it might be a matter of taste, I think they only aid readability for spaces and characters that need to be escaped. This can be shortened:

```
/^([a-z]+)(?:,?\s?)?([a-z]+)?((?:\s)([a-z]))?$/i
```

Maybe it would also be a good idea to nest some of your optional groups. For example, there is no reason to allow a second name if there is no comma or space to delimit it:

```
/^([a-z]+)(?:(?:,\s?|\s)([a-z]+)?)?(?:\s([a-z]))?$/i
```